# ask a triangle inequality in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If $|z|=2$, and $|w|=3$, then $|z \times w|=6$ and $|z+w|\leq5$ and $|z/w|=\frac{2}{3}$ and $|z-w|\leq5$

Can anyone explain why the last holds? I don't understand why $|z-w|\leq5$

Comment: $|z-w| = |z + (-w)| \le |z| + |-w|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle inequality states that
$$ |a + b| \leq |a| + |b| $$

So, plug $a=z,b=-w$ and we get

$$ |z + (-w) | \leq |z| + |-w| $$

We know that $|xy| = |x| \cdot |y|$, and $|z|=2,|w|=3$. So

$$ |z-w| \leq 3 + 2 \\ |z-w| \leq 5$$